# Google Maps API, JS global variables and Geolocation.watchPosition()

Tags: geolocation, maps

I have been struggling with this piece of javascript for some time now. I have read different, and similar, posts on the subject but I can't find anything that seems to lead me in the right direction of solving my problem.

I need to call the value of the variables from the `watchPosition` (and `getCurrentPosition`) method , set them as global and then call them inside of the `function initMap()`.

The code is working but `watchPosition` reloads the Google map (this appears to happen when i change the browser/switch between tabs). I can't get the global variables to catch the value from the methods below (inside `updateMarker`).

How do I set the values from:

```
mon_lat = +position.coords.latitude;
mon_long = +position.coords.longitude;
```

to become global?

My main question is, more or less: how can i load the script without updating `function initMap()`? I would like it so that the `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition()` method updates automatically.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
updateMarker();
});

var mon_lat = null;
var mon_long = null;
var start_lat = null;
var start_long = null;

function updateMarker() {

  // Get positions
  if (navigator.geolocation) {  

    // Get current position
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
      function (position) {
        mon_lat = +position.coords.latitude;
        mon_long = +position.coords.longitude;
        initMap(mon_lat, mon_long);
      }    
    );

    // Get starting position
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      function (position) {
        start_lat = +position.coords.latitude;
        start_long = +position.coords.longitude;
        initMap(start_lat, start_long);
      }
    );

  }

}

function initMap() {

  // Display the map 
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: mon_lat, lng: mon_long},
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeControl:false
  });

}
```